# Assert if either element exists?

Tags: selenium

I'm using selenium api and want to write a condition that will assert if either of two  elements are present.

Though the only option I see is assertElementPresent(locator) for a single element

Is there a nice way of doing this in Selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For complex condition expressions you can try to use XPath predicates from Webdriver API:

```
  def typeToFieldNamed(label: String, value: Any) {
    val field = webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input|//textarea)[preceding::div[position()=1 and .='" + label + "']]"))
    field.click()
    field.sendKeys(chord(CONTROL, HOME))
    field.sendKeys(chord(CONTROL, SHIFT, END))
    field.sendKeys(value.toString)
  }
```